# SendGrid Email Activity API with no limit returns BadRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Is there any way I can get the email activity from my API key without a limit? According to the documentation, the limit parameter is not required, but any time I don't specify a limit I get a BadRequest response.

```
  public async Task<SentEmailModel> GetEmails()
        {
            var client = new SendGridClient("SENDGRID_API_KEY");
            var queryParams = @"{
                'limit': 100 //I dont't want to specify a limit, since I want to get the full list
            }";
            var response = await client.RequestAsync(method: SendGridClient.Method.GET, urlPath: "messages", queryParams: queryParams);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseString = response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var responseMessages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SentEmailModel>(responseString);
                return responseMessages;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/e-mail-activity/filter-all-messages) says limit is _required_. I can't see any obvious means of paging beyond constructing a query yourself, though that could prove tricky if you send a lot of e-mails at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the docs say the `limit` parameter isn't required, but the API returns an error when you don't provide it. I have notified our docs team to fix this.

However, if the `limit` parameter were optional, it would default to `10` which wouldn't achieve the result you desire.
Some of the APIs you can paginate over to get all the data, but this API does not support pagination.

If you need to go beyond the 1000 limit, I'd recommend setting up the [event webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event) to receive the data in realtime, and retain the data in your application.